# Swift SQLite how to get row.count from table?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

in my Xcode Project, I use SQLite to save user order list

My question is if my data like this 
[image]

Is there any way like table.count and I can get how many row it is ?

Here's my insert method
I hope it can be like this

just create a model, and use directly

```
func insert(_ tableName :String, rowInfo :[String:String]) -> Bool {
    var statement :OpaquePointer? = nil
    let sql = "insert into \(tableName) "
        + "(\(rowInfo.keys.joined(separator: ","))) "
        + "values (\(rowInfo.values.joined(separator: ",")))"

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, sql.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8), -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE {
            return true
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: No its not there, you need to create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let query = "select count(*) from tableName;"
if sqlite3_prepare(self.db, query, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
      while(sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){
           let count = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
           print("\(count)")
      }

}
```

Above code will give you the row count of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure SQLite, you must use SQL requests to get any info from your database. In your case the request will be like this one:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM \(tableName)"
```

But why don't you use CoreData? It has not only a lot of necessary methods to make your data access easier, but also tons of optimisation code for both speed and memory using (what is much more important in my eyes).